# ValueError while making db migrations in django

Tags: python, django

I am new to django and i tried changing `tag` field from `char` field to `TaggableManager()`

models.py

```
class UserBookmark(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    bookmark = models.URLField()
    tag = TaggableManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return '%i %s %s'%(self.id,self.user,self.bookmark)
```

when i run python `manage.py migrate`, i get this error:

> ValueError: Cannot alter field bookmark.UserBookmark.tags into
>   bookmark.UserBookmark.tags - they are not compatible types (you cannot
>   alter to or from M2M fields, or add or remove through= on M2M fields)

How can i remove this error?

Comment: Did you run `makemigrations` before `migrate` ?

Comment: @scharette no i ran migrate first.

Comment: When you make changes to a model you must run `makemigrations` first. It will create the sql commands needed to re-create your changes to the database. Then you can `migrate` those changes.

Comment: @scharette but when i run python manage.py makemigrations, it says no changes detected.

Comment: @avleen01 just try makemigrations <appname>

Comment: @Adeel it says No changes detected in app 'bookmark'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve similar issue by deleting the migration files and sqlite db.

`Make sure to backup your db before deleting`

Comment: ohk can u please explain how can i do that and then again restore my db files?

Comment: And is it important to run these migrations succesfully? like will it hamper the working of my project if these migrations are not sucesful